# can a PORO access the database?

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

as my first Rails app, I am building a homework management app which has these tables:

- users (from Devise authentication)
- schools
- courses
- assignments

Unlike most examples of course/grading apps I've found, this one is never concerned with all the grades for all students for a particular course, but has only a 1:many relationship between student and courses. So the examples don't really help me.

In order to calculate a user's current grade in any given course (which requires access to data in both course model and assignment model), I am following a suggestion from here on Stack Overflow and creating a PORO in the app/models directory called GradeCalculator.

But this is my first experience with building a PORO into a Rails app, and most of the documentation I'm finding online is for more sophisticated users. I'm assuming it doesn't need a controller (please correct me if I'm wrong), and I see that building it is as simple as:

app/models/gradecalculator.rb

```
Class GradeCalculator

  def calculate_current_course_grade(course_id)
    @graded_course_assignments = Assignment.where(user_id: current_user.id, course_id: course_id, graded: true)
    #grab weights for each type of assignment in @graded_course_assignments from courses table
    #do some calculations
    #return the array
  end

  def calculate_user_GPA(current_user.id)
    #more of the same
  end

end
```

My questions are:

1. Can a PORO access the database (to get data from the courses and assignments tables). Or do I need to pass it all the relevant data from my other classes (like assignments) as params when calling it?

   1a. If a simple class can access the database, does the syntax differ from that in the models? Would the above code be able to access Assignment.where?

   1b. How would I call this PORO? For example, how would I call it from my views/assignments/index.html.erb?
2. Can it access Devise's current_user helper?
3. Tangentially, I just realized that I *could* store assignment weights in the assigments table. I was thinking chronologically (user inputs number of homework assignments, quizes, etc. at the time of inputting a new course, which determines the weight for each type of assignment), but I could programmatically have each new assignment populate its own weight field by referencing the number of like assignments from its parent course. This would mean, logically, I could do the grade calculation right in the Assignment model. But if extra credit or other changes were added to the course, all the assignments might then have to recalculate their weights. Which way is more correct?

Writing these questions makes me suspect that I am just to pass my PORO the relevant data from my view, let it do calculations on that data and return a grade. But I will post anyway, just in case I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for breaking business logic out into POROs like this is usually to make your code easier to reason about and easier (and faster) to test. To that end, you do not want GradeCalculator to know or care how Assignment works. You should just pass GradeCalculator all of the data it needs (or a Relation, which quacks like an Enumerable). Having GradeCalculator call `Assignment.where` means that your tests will depend on ActiveRecord, and the database, which means they'll be slow. If GradeCalculator just expects an array, in your tests you'll just have to mock an array of objects that respond to whatever attribute methods GradeCalculator needs to know about, and you'll be able to run them without loading Rails at all. (It's common to have a separate `spec_helper.rb` and `rails_helper.rb` so that specs that don't need Rails can run without loading Rails, which makes them *so* much faster.)

Per your second question my advice is similar: Decouple your POROs as much as possible from Rails and from Devise.

Comment: Thanks! You have confirmed my suspicions and clarified the reason behind them.